# How to plot Gabriel comparison interval in R

Tags: r, plot, comparison

For an unplanned comparisons of means, the Gabriel comparison interval is useful. In SAS, there are CLM and GABRIEL as shown [here](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statanovaunplanned.html). But I want to plot the comparison interval in R so I search for such a function but I failed to find one. I tried to read Gabriel's paper and write one but I was totally lost in the paper. Does anyone know such a function in certain packages or similar function which could plot or give the unplanned comparisons interval? Thanks!

=======================

update(20131213)：
Finally I create a [package](https://github.com/yufree/rgabriel) for Gabriel comparison, yet I still can't find the way to figure out the SMM. The function uses a SMM table from wilcox20.R and could only calculate alpha 0.05 or 0.01 when the samples' number is unequal.

Comment: You need to understand the source enough to be able to write out the equations. If you can do that we can suggest ways to code it up.  Plotting is trivial once you have the results.

Comment: Thank you, In fact I know how to write out the equations but I don't know how to code to get the **studentized maximum modulus**. I also find a [formula](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Falg_cdf-pdf-rand_continuous_smod.htm) to calculate the  **studentized maximum modulus** but I am not a statistician or programmer and I don't know how to code it in R. Could you help me?

Comment: Well, `R` has the `gamma` function, and a couple numerical integration functions.  But if you've got zero `R` experience you'd probably be better off working thru the introductory tutorials first and then coding those equations.